# automatic deletions of AWS Lambdas version

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am having the issue in AWS where it is running out of space due to too many lambdas have too many vertions.

All the resources are specified .yml for cloud formation.

Is there any nice easy way to control it? For example, have an expiration date of the or a max number of versions.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is **no such functionality**. But you could relatively easily develop it yourself. Have a [scheduled CloudWatch Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) that triggers a lambda function. The function checks your versions, lets say, once a week, and delete old ones.

To do it from cloudformation, you would have to define your own [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) or [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) for that.